# 3G USB modem device not detected in iMac

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, device-driver, modem, at-command

I am trying to connect to a 3G USB modem to issue AT commands. But it is not listed in /dev.
In System properties I can see few CDC devices detected. Do I need to install any driver for ACM devices? 
Any thoughts?

Spec : 
Mac OSX 10.6.7.
Intel Core 2 Duo
2GB RAM

Comment: Which 3G modem is it? On some, you have to run modeswitch to turn it from a USB drive to a 3G dongle.